# Как настроить протон под Fedora 34?

Tags: linux, fedora, steam

Столкнулся недавно с проблемой, а именно не удается запустить любую игру в стим. когда я нажимаю "Играть" у меня на мгновение появятся окно с текстом "Prepearing to launch *название игры*...", затем сразу пропадает и в результате игра не запускается.

То что я уже пробовал - обновить драйвер видеокарты, попробовать параметры запуска игры (gamemoderun% comand% и еще один, сейчас не вспомню)

Вот результат команды neofetch

```
:-------------------::        ------------------------ 
     :-----------/shhOHbmp---:\      OS: Fedora 34 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
   /-----------omMMMNNNMMD  ---:     Host: HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec0xxx 
  :-----------sMMMMNMNMP.    ---:    Kernel: 5.12.9-300.fc34.x86_64 
 :-----------:MMMdP-------    ---\   Uptime: 24 mins 
,------------:MMMd--------    ---:   Packages: 2002 (rpm), 16 (flatpak) 
:------------:MMMd-------    .---:   Shell: bash 5.1.0 
:----    oNMMMMMMMMMNho     .----:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:--     .+shhhMMMmhhy++   .------/   DE: GNOME 40.1 
:-    -------:MMMd--------------:    WM: Mutter 
:-   --------/MMMd-------------;     WM Theme: Adwaita 
:-    ------/hMMMy------------:      Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
:-- :dMNdhhdNMMNo------------;       Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
:---:sdNMMMMNds:------------:        Terminal: gnome-terminal 
:------:://:-------------::          CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mo 
:---------------------://            GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Picasso 
                                     GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max- 
                                     Memory: 3750MiB / 13964MiB
```

Вот результат команды df -T

```
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs       devtmpfs   7092108        0   7092108   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      7149756        0   7149756   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs      2859904     2200   2857704   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 btrfs    498443264 56067608 442050104  12% /
/dev/nvme0n1p3 btrfs    498443264 56067608 442050104  12% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2 ext4        999320   313036    617472  34% /boot
/dev/loop0     squashfs    212096   212096         0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/code/65
/dev/loop1     squashfs    101632   101632         0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/11167
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat        613184    16468    596716   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs      7149756      104   7149652   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs      1429948      948   1429000   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Я бы попробовал сделать образ всей системы на отдельный внешний накопитель, на буке всё снести и поставить последний lts убунты и посмотреть там. Если там тоже задница - значит проблема глубже, чем просто в наборе прог. Если едет - смотреть какие именно версии дров\ядер\модулей и на сколько отличаются.